# Are there any sampradayas that subscribe to Advaita and gyan yoga?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, jnana, srisampraday

There are numerous bhakti yoga-based sampradayas in India, especially Vaishnavas. They keep bhakti and puranic texts forefront (which I don't really see among other Hindu sects). Are there any sampradayas or sects that keep Upanishads at the forefront and subscribe to the path of Gyan yoga prominently - such as reading, self-inquiry, and meditation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Purely Jnanayoga based sampradayas, then Outside of the Shaankara Advaita sampradaya, there aren't any. However, there are a few sampradayas which allow for the concept of Jnana-mishra-bhakti. (i.e. a combination of bhakti and jnana yoga). For them, Bhakti is incomplete without Jnanayoga. Take for example, the Utkaliya Vaishnavas.

Quoting from [here](https://magazines.odisha.gov.in/Orissareview/2014/Jun/engpdf/115-119.pdf)

> **dui je deṇāre pakṣī uḍikari jāi, dui je cakṣure sehi saṃsāre khelai. eka je na thile kaṇā dui gale anḍha, eṇukari nirguṇa saguṇa sehi
> bheda.**
>
> A bird can only fly with both wings. It can have a perfect vision with
> both the eyes. In the absence of one, it becomes one-eyed, and in the
> absence of both, it is totally blind. Thus like two eyes Nirguna [god
> perceived as formless]and Saguna [god perceived with form] are chained
> together
>
> **Gurubhakti Gita by Achyutananda Dasa(A Stalwart of Utkaliya Vaisnavism).**

Similarly, Varakari Vaishnava sampradaya of Maharashtra, Although primarily a Bhakti-based Sampradaya, Follows it in conjunction with the Non-dualistic teachings of Advaita vedanta.

Citing from Ekanathi Bhagavat of [Shri Ekanath Maharaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eknath) of Varkari sampradaya-

> **वंदूं आचार्य शंकरु ।  जो का ग्रंथार्थविवेक चतुरु । सारुनि कर्मठतेचा विचारु । प्रबोध दिनकरु प्रकाशिला ॥**
>
> I bow down to **Acharya Shankara, who is an adept in bringing out the
> true purport of the Shastric texts**, who has made the Sun of
> Jnana-marga shine after having set aside the Karma-pradhana
> interpretations (of the upanishads)
>
> **~ श्री एकनाथ महाराज, एकनाथी भागवत**

Comment: Oh I see, there aren't any authentic sampradayas capable of jnana yoga now. Thank you for the answer.